# Page Object Pattern Circular import problem in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, pageobjects

I'm writing my automation framework in Page Object Pattern and I've came across this error when implementing view classes. I've placed this classes in separate modules and I want them to stay separated. The problem is that I want my instance methods in both classes to return an object of another class when performing certain UI actions.

Is there a way to fix circular error while having this classes in separate modules?

**cart_page.py**

```py
from pages.base_page import BasePage
from utils.locators import CartLocators
from pages.main_page import MainPage

class CartPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.locators = CartLocators()
        super().__init__(driver, 'https://www.saucedemo.com/cart.html')

    def click_continue_shopping(self):
        self.find_element(*self.locators.CONTINUE_SHOPPING_BTN).click()
        return MainPage(self.driver)
```

**main_page.py**

```py
from pages.base_page import BasePage
from utils.locators import MainPageHeaderLocators, MainPageItemListLocators, InventoryItemLocators
from pages.cart_page import CartPage

class MainPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver, "https://www.saucedemo.com/invetory.html")
        self.header = MainPageHeader(self.driver)
        self.item_list = MainPageItemList(self.driver)
        self.inventory_item = InventoryItemPage(self.driver)

    def open_cart(self):
        self.header.open_cart()
        return CartPage(self.driver)
```

```
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'MainPage' from partially initialized module 'pages.main_page' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/marcin94/PycharmProjects/sauce_demo_ui_tests/pages/main_page.py)
```

Comment: You can always import MainPage in your ``click_continue_shopping()`` function in ``cart_page.py``.  That would get rid of the circular dependency.

Comment: usually you only need write some common functions in MainPage, I guess open_cart() is to do some particular thing

Comment: @saquintes Do you think it's clean enough solution?

Comment: That's probably a matter of opinion.  I've done it myself when I have to get around circular dependencies.  The code for ``import <...>`` is pretty performant when it's already imported.  But if I can re-work how things are organized to avoid the dependency altogether, that's my preference.  But sometimes it just doesn't make sesne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `from`. Import the module directly:

**cart_page.py**

```
from pages.base_page import BasePage
from utils.locators import CartLocators
import pages.main_page

class CartPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.locators = CartLocators()
        super().__init__(driver, 'https://www.saucedemo.com/cart.html')

    def click_continue_shopping(self):
        self.find_element(*self.locators.CONTINUE_SHOPPING_BTN).click()
        return pages.main_page.MainPage(self.driver)
```

**main_page.py**

```
from pages.base_page import BasePage
from utils.locators import MainPageHeaderLocators, MainPageItemListLocators, InventoryItemLocators
import pages.cart_page

class MainPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver, "https://www.saucedemo.com/invetory.html")
        self.header = MainPageHeader(self.driver)
        self.item_list = MainPageItemList(self.driver)
        self.inventory_item = InventoryItemPage(self.driver)

    def open_cart(self):
        self.header.open_cart()
        return pages.cart_page.CartPage(self.driver)
```

Comment: Well I think that's it. Still trying to figured out how circular actually appear.

Comment: They appear when you try to import A, and then at the top of the page, A tries to import B, and then at the top of the page B tries to import A.  If it works, it works, but I don't see how this answer solves the problem.  I would expect it to still cause a circular dependency problem.

Comment: @saquintes Because Python tracks all "already loaded" modules. So, when in the second module you import the first module, Python recognizes it as already loaded, so it saves the reference to it and keeps going.